# If a $\int_{\partial R} \omega =0$ with $\partial R$ the boundary of a rectangle in an open disc $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, then $\omega$ is exact

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-forms, complex-integration

In Cartan's book there is a proof that considers $\omega=Pdx + Qdy$, but I want to consider $\omega=f(z)dz$ (even though that's the same, I know). The proof I have doesn't work at one point because I would need that (given $h=x+iy$ the small increment) $\frac{|x|+|y|}{h} \to 1$, which isn't true.

So I would like to prove the statement in the theorem, that is

"If given a differential form $\omega=f(z)dz$ we have that $\int_{\partial R} \omega =0$ with $\partial R$ the boundary of a rectangle in an open disc $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, then $\omega$ is exact in $U$"

This is my attempt:

I define $F(z)= \int_{\gamma} \omega$, where $\gamma$ is a path connecting a point $z_0$ (fixed) and $z$ through the sides of the rectangle whose vertices are $z_0$ and $z$. Then I take $z+h$ and I obtain:

$$F(z+h)-F(z)= \int_{\gamma_{h}} \omega$$

where $\gamma_h$ is the path connecting $z$ and $z+h$ (let's say $h=h_1 + ih_2$). Adding and subtracting $f(z) \int_{\gamma_{h}} du = f(z)L(\gamma_h)$ I obtain

$$F(z+h)-F(z)=f(z)*L(\gamma_h) + \int_{\gamma_{h}} f(u)-f(z) du$$

where $f(z)$ is fixed and $L(\gamma_h)$ is the length of the path, which is $|h_1| +|h_2|$ because it follows the sides of a rectangle. Then I would like to divide by $h$ and conclude, but the problem is that $\frac{|h_1|+|h_2|}{h}$ doesn't tend to 1 in general, so I can't conclude.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Crostul to prove the statement in the title considering $\omega= f(z)dz$ and not $\omega=Pdx + Qdy$. I haven't given many details because I thought this was a very very famous and basic theorem of complex analysis, which everybody knew (the final part of the question is in fact useless, it basically says "I have tried to do that, but I failed")

Comment: Please share your attempt of proof. We cannot help you with it else.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff done